# How to initialize weights when using RELU activation function

Tags: theano, conv-neural-network

I want to make a Conv network and I wish to use the RELU activation function. Can someone please give me a clue of the correct way to initialize weights (I'm using Theano)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a hard and fast best way to initialize weights and bias for a ReLU layer.

Some [claim](http://deepdish.io/2015/02/24/network-initialization/) that (a slightly modified version of) Xavier initialization works well with ReLUs. Others that small Gaussian random weights plus bias=1 (ensuring the weighted sum of positive inputs will remain positive and thus not end up in the ReLUs zero region).

In Theano, these can be achieved like this (assuming weights post-multiply the input):

```
w = theano.shared((numpy.random.randn((in_size, out_size)) * 0.1).astype(theano.config.floatX))
b = theano.shared(numpy.ones(out_size))
```

or

```
w = theano.shared((numpy.random.randn((in_size, out_size)) * tt.sqrt(2 / (in_size + out_size))).astype(theano.config.floatX))
b = theano.shared(numpy.zeros(out_size))
```

Comment: The problem they all end up with high value and so Nan cost in the system. unless you are using gradient clipping.